# Is there a easy way to implement scroll to top on iOS when tap status bar?

Tags: flutter

It's easier Listen ScrollView offset by new ScrollController more than ScrollNotification, But Primary ScrollViews obtain their ScrollController via inheritance from a PrimaryScrollController widget. You cannot both set primary to true and pass an explicit controller. So, Custom ScrollController broken scroll to top on iOS when tap status bar.

Comment: There are lots of custom ScrollController in my project. It's hard to change.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble registering a tap in the status bar or notch on an iOS device, I suggest you try [`scrolls_to_top` package](https://pub.dev/packages/scrolls_to_top). Then you can write some code for `onScrollsToTop` that works similar to [Flutter's implementation for scrolling to the top](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/affba75f2efc10c43dfaf19e41863e45673806f3/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart#LL91C3-L102C4).